# How to expand 2 textboxes (out of three) equally when one of them is collapsed?

Tags: wpf, layout, width

I have three textboxes...inside a stack panel (orientation  = Horizontal).

each has same width. If one of them is collapsed, I want other two to share the space.

I mean if 15o was total width (50 * 3). If one is collapsed, each textbox should occupy 75.

Please help me to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to put them into a UniformGrid. If you set it to `Rows="1"`, then it will make one column for each (non-collapsed) child, and make all the columns equal widths.

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1" Width="150">
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
</UniformGrid>
```